# How to return multiple output parameters from stored procedure for C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm using output parameters to get values from my database.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCustomerMainData] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @Reference nvarchar(100),
        @SubscriptionPIN nvarchar(100) OUTPUT,
        @SignupDate nvarchar(100) OUTPUT,
        @ProductCount int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @SubscriptionPIN = 'N/A'
    SET @SignupDate = 'N/A'
    SET @ProductCount = 0

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS(SELECT [SubscriptionPIN] FROM [Norton].[dbo].[Customers] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @SubscriptionPIN = [SubscriptionPIN], @SignupDate = SignUpDate  FROM [Norton].[dbo].[ProductList] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference
        SET @ProductCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Norton].[dbo].[ProductList] WHERE [Reference] = @Reference)
    END

    RETURN (@SubscriptionPIN)
    RETURN (@SignupDate)
    RETURN (@ProductCount)
END
```

I'm not sure about the returns at the end:

```
RETURN (@SubscriptionPIN)
RETURN (@SignupDate)
RETURN (@ProductCount)
```

On the other side, here is the c# code :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetCustomerMainData", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reference", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CustomerReferenceID;

        SqlParameter SubscriptionPIN = new SqlParameter("@TheCustomerID", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(SubscriptionPIN);

        SqlParameter SignupDate = new SqlParameter("@SignupDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(SignupDate);

        SqlParameter ProductCount = new SqlParameter("@ProductCount", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ProductCount);

        con.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (cmd.Parameters["@TheCustomerID"].Value.ToString() != "N/A")
            {
                aStatus.SubscriptionPIN = cmd.Parameters["@TheCustomerID"].Value.ToString();
                aStatus.SignupDate = cmd.Parameters["@SignupDate"].Value.ToString();
                aStatus.ProductCount = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ProductCount"].Value.ToString());
                aStatus.Result = "0: Reference ID Found";
             }
             else
             {
                 aStatus.Result = "1: Reference ID does not exists";
                 return aStatus;
             }
          }
          catch (SqlException sqlExc)
          {
              foreach (SqlError error in sqlExc.Errors)
              {
                  aStatus.Result = string.Format("{0}: {1}", error.Number, error.Message);
                  return aStatus;
              }
          }
      }
}
```

When I run this code, I get error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection
>   parameters)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I don't know what is the correct way to send many output parameters from stored procedure, can someone help please?

Comment: You don't use `RETURN` for output parameters you just assign a value to them inside the procedure. If there is more than one matching row in `ProductList WHERE Reference = @Reference` (i.e. `@ProductCount` is `>1`) then it is undeterministic what rows will be used when assigning to `@SubscriptionPIN, @SignupDate`. Also from the error message you are getting looks like you need to use [`SqlParameter(String, SqlDbType, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Martin, didn't notice your reply at the beginning, but its very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the maximum length for the `nvarchar` parameters:

```
SqlParameter SubscriptionPIN = new SqlParameter("@TheCustomerID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
cmd.Parameters.Add(SubscriptionPIN);
SqlParameter SignupDate = new SqlParameter("@SignupDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
cmd.Parameters.Add(SignupDate);
```

Remove the `return` statements from the stored procedure. You don't need to do anything for the output parameters to be returned. (Also, you can only use one `return` statement, and you can only return integer values. You would use a parameter with the direction `ReturnValue` to get that returned value.)

Answer (score 2):

Procedure execution ends after your first RETURN which "Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure."

Consider returning both values as one recordset with

```
SELECT @SubscriptionPIN AS SubsPIN , @SignupDate AS SignUpDate, @ProductCount AS ProdCount
```

at the end of the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I change it but I still get error at when execute, is there any changes in C# code need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried and it is working fine

```
**Stored Procedures**

STORED PROCEDURE 1

create procedure spLoginCount
@userid nvarchar(50),
@password nvarchar(50),
@count int out
as 
Begin 
    select @count=count(userid) from users where userid=@userid and pswd=@password
End



**STORED PROCEDURE 2**

create procedure spLoginData
@userid nvarchar(50),
@usertype nvarchar(20) out,
@lastlogin nvarchar(100) out
as 
Begin 
    select @usertype=usertype,@lastlogin=lastlogin from users where userid=@userid
End


**ASP.NET code which will get values of two output Parameters**....



 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uid="", psw="";
        uid = txtUserName.Text;
        psw = txtPassword.Text;

         string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
         using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(cs))
         {
             SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("spLoginCount", scon);
             scmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid",uid);
             scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", psw);

             SqlParameter outparameter = new SqlParameter();
             outparameter.ParameterName = "@count";
             outparameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
             outparameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
             scmd.Parameters.Add(outparameter);

             scon.Open();
             scmd.ExecuteScalar();

             string count = outparameter.Value.ToString();
             if (count == "1")
             {
                 SqlCommand scmd1= new SqlCommand("spLoginData", scon);
                 scmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", uid);

                 /*SqlParameter outUserType = new SqlParameter();
                 outUserType.ParameterName = "@usertype";
                 outUserType.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NText;
                 outUserType.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                 scmd1.Parameters.Add(outUserType);
                 */
                 SqlParameter outUserType = new SqlParameter("@usertype", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                 scmd1.Parameters.Add(outUserType);

                 SqlParameter outLastLogin = new SqlParameter("@lastlogin", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                 scmd1.Parameters.Add(outLastLogin);

                 scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 scon.Close();

                 string usertype,lastlogin;
                 usertype = outUserType.Value.ToString();
                 lastlogin = outLastLogin.Value.ToString();
               }

             }
         }
```

Comment: Can you please try to reformat your answer so it doesn't all show as code? Thanks.

Comment: This is actually a very good answer because it shows how to get the data from the output parameters once the stored procedure has executed.

Answer (score 1):

**>Try this its working fine for the multiple output parameter:**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStringEndicia"].ConnectionString)){

                using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("endicia.credentialLookup", sqlConnection))
                { 

                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", accountNumber);
                    SqlParameter outLogin = new SqlParameter("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(outLogin);
                    SqlParameter outPassword = new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(outPassword);
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string login, password;
                    login = outLogin.Value.ToString();
                    password = outPassword.Value.ToString();                        
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlParameter SubscriptionPIN = new SqlParameter("@TheCustomerID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
cmd.Parameters.Add(SubscriptionPIN);
SqlParameter SignupDate = new SqlParameter("@SignupDate", **DbType.String, 100**) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
cmd.Parameters.Add(SignupDate);

must give type and size