# Stored Procedures Basic Help Getting Totals Back From table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

This is my stored procedure, the query returns a table with three columns with a total amount within each column.

UnitPrice, Tax, OrderTotal

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TaxOrderReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @TaxReturnValue int,
    @TotalReturnValue int,
    @UnitReturnValue int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT Sum(oi.UnitPrice) as UnitPrice, Sum(oi.Tax) as Tax,
        Sum(oi.TotalAmount) as OrderTotal
     FROM OrderItems oi, Orders o
     where @StartDate <= o.OrderDate and O.OrderDate <= @EndDate 
        and o.OrderId = oi.OrderId

    select @TaxReturnValue as Tax
    select @UnitReturnValue as UnitPrice
    select @TotalReturnValue as OrderTotal

    -- How can I return several values over?? 
    return @TaxReturnValue

END
```

My goal is to have an admin input dates and get a report back of total sales tax and money before tax generated for him. This is what my method looks like in my controller.

```
public ActionResult GetTaxReport(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_TaxOrderReport", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = EndDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var returnvalue = cmd.Parameters["@TaxReturnValue"].Value.ToString();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return View("FindUser");
}
```

The @TaxReturnValue is not getting set to the value from the column, I cant seem to find a way of setting all three of these variables and then returning them all so I can render them in my view. If anyone has any tips i would appreciate it.

```
-----UPDATE--------------
```

Thought I would update the question to contain the answer just in case anyone needs a very explicit answer regarding how to return and set variables passed in to a stored procedure.

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TaxOrderReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @TaxReturnValue int OUTPUT,
    @TotalRevenue int OUTPUT,
    @UnitReturnValue int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    --Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT
        @TaxReturnValue = Sum(oi.Tax), 
        @UnitReturnValue = Sum(oi.UnitPrice),
        @TotalRevenue = Sum(oi.TotalAmount)
     FROM OrderItems oi, Orders o
     where @StartDate <= o.OrderDate and O.OrderDate <= @EndDate 
        and o.OrderId = oi.OrderId

END
```

C# Code:

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_TaxOrderReport", connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = EndDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalRevenue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;


                cmd.Parameters["@TaxReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters["@TotalRevenue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters["@UnitReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var taxTotal = cmd.Parameters["@TaxReturnValue"].Value;
                var unitPriceTotal = cmd.Parameters["@UnitReturnValue"].Value;
                var totalRenuve = cmd.Parameters["@TotalRevenue"].Value;

            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you need to set the `ParameterDirection` otherwise `@TaxReturnValue` does not get returned:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

cmd.Parameters["@TaxReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

However, that would still not return your value as you are not correctly populating them. You should do this instead:

```
SELECT @TaxReturnValue = Sum(oi.UnitPrice) as UnitPrice, 
    @UnitReturnValue=Sum(oi.Tax),
    TotalReturnValue =Sum(oi.TotalAmount) as OrderTotal
 FROM OrderItems oi, Orders o
 where @StartDate <= o.OrderDate and O.OrderDate <= @EndDate 
    and o.OrderId = oi.OrderId

--select @TaxReturnValue as Tax
--select @UnitReturnValue as UnitPrice
--select @TotalReturnValue as OrderTotal
```

You should then specify these variables as `OUTPUT` parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TaxOrderReport]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date,
    @TaxReturnValue int OUTPUT,
    @TotalReturnValue int OUTPUT,
    @UnitReturnValue int OUTPUT
AS
```

You need to something similar in C#:

```
cmd.Parameters["@TaxReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters["@TotalReturnValue "].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters["@UnitReturnValue "].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Alternatively, you could return a result set using the select statement( without using variables), see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188655.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hey friend I tried adding this however its still returns 0. Is there a way in which I can manipulate the whole 3 columned table as an object and get the values from there? The variagles are not getting set in the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks man updated the question to contain the corrected edited code. Answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the output variable on the parameter you want to return in the procedure

```
...
@EndDate date,
@TaxReturnValue int output,
@TotalReturnValue int,
...
```

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884461/how-to-return-multiple-output-parameters-from-stored-procedure-for-c-sharp-funct) too